# Use pandas in a django view function to load data from a csv

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv

I want to display time series data in a django application. The data is currently available in a csv-format. The simplest solution that came to my mind was to load the data using pandas in the view function, then perform my desired processing with it and supply the processed data to the HTML template in the context dictionary:

```
def view_function(request):
    df = pd.read_csv('data/test.csv')

    # Any further processing of the loaded Dataframe 
    # that returns df_processed

    context = { 'data':  df_processed}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

However, since I am new to web development, I wondered if this would be the way how to do it or if there are actually severe problems attached to this solution? If yes, what would be a better way how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is some added overhead to utilizing pandas here if you don't use it anywhere else. The standard way of opening a csv file in python is

```
with open('data/test.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        # Any further processing here
```

But you might want to look at just storing this file in a database and using the standard django ORM in the models section of your application instead.